# Filter rows of a 2d array using multiple mathematical conditions

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, filtering

I need to retain rows in my multidimensional array where multiole conditions must be met.

```
$positions = [
    ['64', '64', 'home.png', 'www.sdsd.vf'],
    ['128', '640', 'icon-building64.png', 'www.sdsd232.vf']
];

for ($i = 0; $i < 700; $i += 64) {
    for($j = 0; $j < 1100; $j += 64) {
        $out = array_filter(
            $positions, 
            function($position) {
                  return ($position[0] == $j AND $position[1] == $i);
             });    
        $out = array_merge(array(), $out);
    }
}
```

I tried this but I get errors:

```
$out = array_filter(
    $positions,
    function($position, $i, $j) {
        return ($position[0] == $j AND $position[1] == $i);
    }
);
```

Comment: You are aware that both your `for` loops got no ending `}` (and one doesn't have `{`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consolidate all conditions inside of a solitary `array_filter()` call.

```
function filterPositions($value) {
    return $value[0] < 1100
           && $value[1] < 700
           && ($value[0] % 64 == 0)
           && ($value[1] % 64 == 0);
}
$out = array_filter($positions, 'filterPositions');
```

Or a more concise and modern version with arrow function syntax.

```
var_export(
    array_filter(
        $positions,
        fn($row) =>
            $row[0] < 1100
            && $row[1] < 700
            && ($row[0] % 64 == 0)
            && ($row[1] % 64 == 0)
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this, is passing the `$i` and `$j` to your anonymous function

```
$out = array_filter($positions, function($position) use ($i, $j) {
                  return ($position[0] == $j AND $position[1] == $i);
    });
```

This way you will be avoiding hardcoding values in function.